# What Did The Actor Say Here?

Tags: listening

At [2:57 into the movie clip](https://youtu.be/V3Gnq8VFai4?t=2m57s), the actor says this line:

> You want me to ________________________ see if I got a hacky sack for you to throw and do absolutely nothing with?

I can't figure out what he said in the blank. (Not that the rest is 100% correct, so you might want to check the entire sentence and correct anything wrong even outside the blank.)

What did he say?

Comment: "You want me to reach in here and see if I got a hacky sack?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its very unclear. One character finds a boomerang in a backpack, the other throws it at the enemies, missing them completely.

It's hard to hear exactly what is said but it appears to be a rhetorical question. Meaning *Do you want me to get you another useless weapon?*

I hear:

> Nice work(irony). You want me to reach in here and see if I got a hacky sack for you throw and do absolutely nothing with(?)

A hacky-sack is a sand filled ball, not effective as a weapon.

Of course 30 seconds later the boomerang comes back and takes out all four motorbikes.